# Error installing SQL Server Management Studio 17.6 , 18.5 code : 0x800b0003

Tags: installation, ssms

hi guys i got above error when install ssms 2022 and in my update windows one item is downloaded ...
how can i pass this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIxWz.png)

and this is my error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlF8I.png)

i wand to install ssms and get thes error

Comment: SQL is a _language_, and can't be installed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: Your title says SSMS 17, but your question references the SSMS 2022; something that doesn't exist. There *was* a release of SSMS in 2022, but that was SSMS 19.